# Hatcher's natural map $h:H^{n}(C;G) \rightarrow Hom(H_{n}(C),G)$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In the process of trying to find a relationship between homology and cohomology groups, Hatcher defines a map $h:H^{n}(C;G) \rightarrow Hom(H_{n}(C),G)$. He wants to show that this map is surjective, and in the process he produces a homomorphism $Hom(H_{n}(C);G) \rightarrow H^{n}(C;G)$ and says that if we follow this map by $h$, we get the identity map on $Hom(H_{n}(C);G)$, therefore $h$ is surjective.

> I am confused as to why this implies that $h$ is surjective. At first glance, I took it that he was constructing a right inverse for $h$ which would imply surjectivity. But this appears to be a left inverse which would imply *injectivity.* What am I missing here? Details are on page 191/192 of Hatcher if needed.

Comment: More generally, if $h\circ g$ is surjective, then $h$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g : \operatorname{Hom}(H_n(X), G) \to H^n(C; G)$ be the other map. Hatcher claims that if $h\circ g = \operatorname{id}$ then $h$ is surjective. This is true. To see this, note that for any $\alpha \in \operatorname{Hom}(H_n(C), G)$, we have

$$\alpha = \operatorname{id}(\alpha) = (h\circ g)(\alpha) = h(g(\alpha))$$

so $\alpha$ belongs to the image of $h$.

Comment: Oh of course ! (Facepalm) I just made a stupid Friday afternoon error and wrote down as $g \circ h$.